# can't increment a variable inside a loop in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, script, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am running a bash script in Ubuntu 18.04. The script needs to run a python script 10 times. I did the following `testbash.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=1
while [ $count -le 9 ]
do
python /home/e/Documents/codemycode/test.py
((count++))
echo $count
done
```

This generates the error:

```
./testbash.sh: 5: ./testbash.sh: count++: not found
```

I also tried to replace the ((count++) with:

```
count = $(expr $count+1)
```

But also was not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) specifies `sh` as the interpreter. `((count++))` doesn't work in `sh`, it works in `bash`. Change the shebang to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

---

The following syntax is supported by `sh`:

```
count=$(($count+1))
```

or even

```
count=$((count+1))
```

As far as I know this is a portable (POSIX) way.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just a side question: why two brackets? can't one or no brackets work?

Comment: @user9371654 `a++` will try to run `a++` -- like alias, function or executable. `(a++)` will try to run `a++` in a subshell. The syntax you need had to be defined in a different way and somebody chose two brackets.